# labels as values vs. switch statement

Tags: c, gcc

I read recently about labels as values,

```
int main(){
    int value  = 2;
    const void *labels[] = {&&val_0, &&val_1, &&val_2};
    goto *labels[value];
    val_0:
        printf("The value is 0\n");
        goto end;
    val_1:
        printf("The value is 1\n");
        goto end;
    val_2:
        printf("The value is 2\n");
        goto end;
    end:
    return(0);
}
```

what I am asking about is that, is there really any performance gain from using this method instead of using switch statement, or array of pointers?

Answer (score 4):

This is a non-standard extension, is likely to perform no better than the equivalent switch statement in this case and is, IMHO, should be avoided. A switch statement is clearer and more maintainable.

(I quickly tested my version of gcc and it produced exactly the same code for both this code and a switch statement equivalent. It wasn't a representative test, though, as it optimized everything out except for the code path actually chosen.)

One potential performance consideration is that the switch statement must have reasonable behaviour even if `value` isn't in the correct range, your version has undefined behaviour so the compiler may be able to avoid a range check in some code.

Comment: so why it is added in gcc compiler ?

Comment: I don't know, probably to support cases where the address of a dynamically chose label is stored for use later in a function.

Comment: This is known as direct threading and has significant advantages over using switch in very performance sensitive sections, due to only incurring a single branch misprediction. Still you are right that it should not be used as a common substitute for the switch statement where performance isn't a concern.

Comment: Agree with @MartinKällman . For example: Erlang/OTP has that one particular file, `beam_emu.c`, that when compiled without label-as-value gcc extension, makes whole Erlang 30-40% slower.

Comment: @Martin this is actually untrue in most versions of GCC - it pessimizes the code back down to a switch statement behind the scenes and goes back to frequent mispredictions. It's pretty much useless for direct threading as a result.

Comment: @Leushenko try storing the label addresses in an array and then dynamically jump to it based on the array index. this is a very common way to implement VMs, and is well-known in CS as well as industry. from my own experience I can't say that I agree with you, either; maybe you constructed a trivial case that the compiler decided to optimize away?

Comment: @MartinKällman Take [the direct threading example](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/threading/direct.c) on Anton Ertl's threading page. The generated assembly load the jump point into `rax`, statically jumps to a dispatch point at the end, then from that one location makes the dynamic jump to the pointer in `rax`, for a near-100% mispredict rate. This is true for recent versions of GCC and Clang, and there's no reason why it wouldn't do this for pointers stored in an array unless you violated the label values scoping rules (which is UB).

Comment: @Leushenko other than by the property of temporal coherence (or more appropriately, the predictor logic), you will always have one compulsory misprediction. this is inherent to any form of dynamic dispatch. these slides contain a good overview of VM dispatch mechanisms (I recommend reading the paper, too): http://bit.ly/1meoEXD

Comment: @MartinKällman the technique exists, and it makes sense if you implement it in assembly; my point is that GCC and related compilers possess an optimisation *specifically designed to defeat* the technique (crossjumping; I don't know offhand why it does this). GCC will *not emit* dynamic jump code for a goto-value statement, so the technique is not especially useful when working in C because what is generated is not what you wrote. Just examine the actual output.

Answer (score 4):

The answer lies in the assembly code generated by gcc (`-g` and `-O2`). The two functions take `value` as argument, which is first asked to the user (to force gcc not to eliminate unused pieces of code - aka *dead code elimination*). Of course, the `printf` part is the same for both functions and gcc optimized (both) so that it returns right after printing. So the significant part is the beginning of both functions. Let's give them a look:

- goto function:

```
0x080484d0 <+0>:    push   %ebp                      # -
0x080484d1 <+1>:    mov    %esp,%ebp                 #  |- standard prologue
0x080484d3 <+3>:    sub    $0x28,%esp                # -
0x080484d6 <+6>:    mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax            # get argument
0x080484d9 <+9>:    movl   $0x80484f8,-0x14(%ebp)    # set up labels array
0x080484e0 <+16>:   movl   $0x8048510,-0x10(%ebp)
0x080484e7 <+23>:   movl   $0x8048528,-0xc(%ebp)
0x080484ee <+30>:   jmp    *-0x14(%ebp,%eax,4)       # jump to appropriate sect.
0x080484f2 <+34>:   lea    0x0(%esi),%esi
```

- switch function:

```
0x08048470 <+0>:    push   %ebp                      # -
0x08048471 <+1>:    mov    %esp,%ebp                 #  |- standard prologue
0x08048473 <+3>:    sub    $0x18,%esp                # -
0x08048476 <+6>:    mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax            # get argument
0x08048479 <+9>:    cmp    $0x1,%eax
0x0804847c <+12>:   je     0x80484b8 <switchFunc+72> # jump here if value == 1
0x0804847e <+14>:   cmp    $0x2,%eax
0x08048481 <+17>:   je     0x80484a0 <switchFunc+48> # if value == 2
0x08048483 <+19>:   test   %eax,%eax
0x08048485 <+21>:   jne    0x804849b <switchFunc+43> # if value != 0 return
```

Both snippets have a 'slow part': the first one spends most of the time setting up the labels array whereas the second one is slow deciding which path to choose. So, basically, their execution times are almost identical.
Which one is better then? The second one, the one with the `switch` construct. It is standard C, much more readable, maintainable and clear.

Comment: @Mr.32: First, you have to compile with debug symbols included (-g switch on gcc). Then using a program such as gdb (the command is `disass <function_name>`, only assembly code) or, even better objdump (`objdump <program> -S -d`, C code intermixed with asm)

Comment: @Mr.32: no problem, have fun with it :)

Comment: @BlackBear, @Mr.32,  at least with gcc there is a much simpler method to obtain the assembler: just compile with `-S` instead of `-c`.

Comment: @Jens Gustedt: of course! But you know, you forget always the simplest things! ;)

Comment: And the generated assembler is less unreadable if you compile with `gcc -fverbose-asm -S` (and other flags, like `-O`)

Comment: This answer is incorrect in the context of the question: he is asking for performance differences, and using switch will be significantly slower due to branch mispredictions which stall the pipeline. As you can see from your own assembly code, the switch statement litters the code with jumps, which is where the CPU is spending most of its time - not doing a few moves and subtractions.

Comment: @MartinKällman I see your point but thanks to speculative execution branch mispredictions will hardly slow things that much

Comment: @BlackBear Speculative execution that fails, i.e. the branch predictor mispredicts the path taken, still causes a pipeline flush. Speculative execution is only beneficial when the prediction is successful. A switch statement is the worst case for both prediction and speculative execution. (Applies to commodity x86, IA64 works differently)

Answer (score 3):

I think that a switch statement is more readable and cleaner, so use that rather than an array unless the problem does not fit a switch statement very well.

The best use of **label  as value** is in an interpreter for threaded code :

> The labels within the interpreter function can be stored in the
>   threaded code for super-fast dispatching.

Answer (score 3):

However, efficient compilation of `switch` is still an open issue, see e.g. [this paper](http://nextmovesoftware.com/technology/SwitchOptimization.pdf).

And while label as values and indirect `goto`-s are indeed a GCC language extension, it has been adopted by other compilers (`icc`, LLVM/`clang`) and is indeed useful (and is a low-level feature, in the spirit of C), notably for coding threaded code interpreters, automatons, etc.... I don't know why that extension is not becoming standard (I guess it is not standardized because of social or economic factors, not because of technical uselessness.).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the documentation on this feature from the gnu gcc manual
http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Labels-as-Values.html