# How to branch conditionally in C to a label given by an arithmetic operation or lookup table

Tags: c, if-statement, conditional-statements, goto

Instead of writing an `if` or a `switch`statement, like this:

```
if (a == 1)
    <some code here 1>
else if (a == 2)
    <some code here 2>
else if (a == 3)
    <some code here 3>
```

I want to run somthing like this:

```
l[1] = here1;
l[2] = here2;
l[3] = here3;

goto l[a];

here1:
    <some code here 1>
here2:
    <some code here 2>
here3:
    <some code here 3>
```

Is it possible to do this in C?

Comment: You want a `switch` statement.

Comment: @dbush, sorry for the previous comment, I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8019849/labels-as-values-vs-switch-statement) which tells me that the `switch` might perform just as well as Labels as Values from the answer below, will try some performance measurements to check it. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, in that question there's an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8019849/labels-as-values-vs-switch-statement/8020107#8020107) that mentions this [paper](https://www.nextmovesoftware.com/technology/SwitchOptimization.pdf) and it seems that what the compiler does when it encounters a `switch` is much more complicated, there are many possible implementations, from simple conditional branches to jump tables to superoptimization. In any case I must check performance.

Comment: I strongly doubt that this would be a performance bottleneck.  As a rule, write code that is readable and trust the compiler to optimize as necessary.  Only optimize by hand if you have a significant measurable slowdown.

Comment: The conditional is reaching hundreds of `case`s, it's not trivial because it should run on a veriety of platforms, and subject to a few different compilers, like ICC besides GCC, so it goes beyond simply testing, perhaps I should provide both implementations to be selected via a compiler option, and let user decide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it isn't but there is a GCC extension for that. https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Labels-as-Values.html#Labels-as-Values.

So your code would be:

```
void *l[3] = {&&here1, &&here2, &&here2};

goto *l[a];

here1:
    <some code here 1>
here2:
    <some code here 2>
here3:
    <some code here 3>
```

Comment: Oh, that's cool, will give it a try. With your tip I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8019849/labels-as-values-vs-switch-statement), which enlightens the comment by @dbush.

Comment: And it seems ICC also implements [labels as values](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/develop/external/us/en/documents/intel-linux-compiler-13-0-gnu-compatibility-rev6.pdf).

Comment: @Arc I had a small missing * over there. Fixed it. Don't blindly copy my code, copy the typo as well, fail and then downvote. And, labels as value, in my experience are usable if you want to loop through the labels at a specific order. Not a common need but labels and labels as values can solve many code readability issues if used properly.